# ¿Cómo saber si estoy usando .NET Core o .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, windows, core

Soy nuevo al mundo de .NET, quiero utilizar .NET Core para desarrollar en lugar de .NET Framework por ser más compatible. Sin embargo, no se cual de los dos estoy usando. Al hacer "dotnet --info" me arroja la información del SDK en uso, pero no me muestra si es Framework o Core, ni me indica cual tengo de cada uno.

Gracias!

Comment: Tal vez te pueda ayudar [este enlace](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-determine-which-version-microsoft-net-framework-installed) para ver lo de .net framework, y [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567353/how-to-determine-if-net-core-is-installed) para .net core, no trabajo con .Net, pero puede que te ayuden

Comment: Si al escribir `dotnet` no recibes el error de que no se pudo encontrar el comando es porque tienes instalada alguna versión de .NET Core. Con el parámetro `--info` puedes saber cuál.

Comment: Igual depende de dónde vayas a escribir el código. Si estás en Visual Studio te van a aparecer plantillas para crear proyectos con .NET Framework y con .NET Core. Si solo quieres generar un proyecto independientemente del IDE, puedes usar el comando [`dotnet new`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consola de dotnet te dará información sobre la versión de la propia aplicación de consola que tienes instalada. Es decir, te informará sobre la versión de la consola, no sobre la versión del framework de tu proyecto.

Si lo que quieres es ver el entorno o la versión de .Net que estás utilizando, debes mirar en el propio archivo del proyecto dado que cada uno de tus proyectos puede utilizar una versión diferente de Framework o Core.

Lo puedes hacer o bien editando el archivo de proyecto (el archivo .csprj que no es más que un archivo XML) o bien desde Visual Studio.

Desde Visual Studio pulsa con el botón secundario del ratón sobre el nodo con el archivo de proyecto y selecciona la opción `Propiedades`.

Esto te abrirá una nueva ventana, en la sección `Aplicación > General > Marco de destino` te informa de la versión que estás utilizando.

En esta misma ventana puedes cambiar la versión que utiliza el proyecto. No en todos los casos, no puedes cambiar de Framework a Core, por ejemplo desde esta ventana.

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió!